# Cron ERROR: Invalid username and/or password (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-job

Our cron has worked without issue then all of a sudden it stopped and provided the error: Civi 5.23.3 WP 5.3

When the cron runs - I get the following:
ERROR: Invalid username and/or password

My cron is as follows:
`/usr/local/bin/php.cli -q /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u username -p password -e Job -a execute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with captcha on our site. The plugin [Captcha by BestWebSoft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha-bws/) and all other captcha's that I have tested, including Wordfence captcha cause cron error. I found a [captcha plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/) that allowed me to restrict registration but not login pages in the mean time.

Comment: Very interesting. I also had this problem just a couple of days ago. I tried switching to wp-cli and it worked (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/). I haven't identified the problem, but I had enabled reCaptcha support in the Wordfence plugin recently!

Comment: Interesting @MarkWestergaard - its good to know I wasn't alone - I wonder what would have been different.

Comment: @MarkWestergaard I can confirm - I just enabled wordfence captcha - same thing.

Comment: I just remembered that when I was trying to determine why cron wasn't running, I tried the HTTP method from a browser and received an email asking me to verify my login attempt because it was flagged as suspicious. I wonder if that's what's happening to cli,php when cron runs with captcha enabled.